# Cloud_Firestore Package Flutter / No debug console errors

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add the cloud_firestore package to my flutter application for web.
After adding the package to dependances app won't run.

Chrome window opens and returns a blank screen. Debug service opens but with no data.

Please help!

Debug console reads

"Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58031/ACok2ufXaZM="

pubspec.yaml is below

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - spread-collections

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  expandable: ^2.2.0
  responsive_builder: ^0.1.2
  get_it:
  provider_architecture:
  #   path: ../provider_architecture
  provider: ^3.1.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Please edit your post with some code.

Comment: Could you share screenshots of what you expected to see and what you are getting, as well as a code snippet of what should be generating content and it is not?